# jQuery custom plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I try to write my first jQuery plugin and i stuck =)
Plugin idea is simple:
initializing on any inputs on forms it add button to it. If input have some value red buttons is appear, if input is empty no buttons. But if some key is pressed - green button appear near input.
Ok. Buttons is appears! But how to ,made them clickable with my plugin hadled?
Here the code:

```
(function($) {
    jQuery.fn.buttonokdel = function(options) {
        var settings = {
            btnDel: null,
            btnOk: null
        };
        var settings = $.extend( {}, settings, options );
        var controlbuttonfunc = function() {
            $(settings.btnOk).on("click", function(){
                alert ($(this).html());
            });
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.val()) {
            $this.after(
                    '<span class="input-group-btn"> \n\
                     <button class="btn btn-danger btno" type="button">\n\
                        &nbsp<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>\n\
                     </button> \n\
                     </span>'
                    );
        } 
        $(this).keyup(function(e) {
            if ($this.next().has("span").length > 0) {
                return false;
            }
            $this.after(
                    '<span class="input-group-btn"> \n\
                      <button class="btn btn-success btyes" type="button")>\n\
                        &nbsp<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>\n\
                     </button> \n\
                     </span>'
                    );
            return true;
        });
    };
    return this.each(controlbuttonfunc);
};
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".inputa").buttonokdel({btnOk:".btyes", btnOk:".btyes"});
});
```

It seems i don't understand some thing with jquery element initialization. Please help me to figure what i do wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this solves your problem, but I'll give it a try: the jQuery on-event should be attached to a static element as your buttons are created dynamically. The static element will delegate the click-event to all children, also for child-elements that are created when the page already loaded.

```
var controlbuttonfunc = function() {
        $(settings.btnOk).on("click", function(){ ...
```

has to be changed into something like

```
var controlbuttonfunc = function() {
        $(document).on("click", ".btn", function(){ ...
```

Instead of $(document) any static parent element can work as container element for event delegation.

Working Demo: [Click event delegation for dynamically added element](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/0q1x8nyr/)

For more information check https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler
section "Direct and delegated events":

> "Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()."

Comment: Yes! It alive! =) I forgot about delegated events! Thank you very much!